# GLPK in python. The interface Pyomo, PuLP or PyGLPK are mandatory?

Tags: python, glpk

I have a Linear Programming(LP) optmisation to solve and I'd like to use GLPK solver. Anyone knows if I can use python to call GLPK? I mean, I can build my program and send to the solver only unsing python without using the interfaces Pyomo or PuLp OR pYglpk? Their sintaxe looks like a little differente from the python sintaxe and I don't know if I will be able to handle it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it works with GLPK, but I know that it is possible with Gurobi. I mean then you should adapt your model in Gurobi modeling syntax. Maybe you should search for "GLPK modelling" on google?

But to be honest, either way you will have to read its documentation and spend time on learning its lib. Pyomo has a better(in my opinion) documentation and better support than any modeling language in python. So better read pyomo doc. and check its basic examples and ask questions here if you encounter with an error. They got a nice developer team here, who answers most of the hard questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've heard about Python-GLPK that look like allow me to model my problem by using conventional matrix way in python.  However, it's not well maintened so as you said I think i have to learn Pyomo.